# Преобразовать кавычки в елочки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Подскажите правильный скрипт преобразования кавычек "" в елочки «»

Comment: [Например][1]. Или по запросу "типограф PHP", выбор есть :)


  [1]: http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/tipograf/

Comment: Регулярными выражениями это НЕ делается — грамматика нерегулярная. Точнее, делается, но только как костыль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держите:

```
$str = '<a href="link">ссылка</a>   Подскажите правильный скрипт преобразования "кавычек" в «елочки»';
$str = preg_replace('/(?:"([^>]*)")(?!>)/', '«$1»', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Одно но: был сделан на скорую руку и "понимает" только одни кавычки в теге. Пока в голове только одно решение есть: это дублировать (?:"([^>]*)")

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'Подскажите правильный скрипт преобразования "кавычек" в «елочки»';

$str = preg_replace('#"(.*?)"#', '«$1»', $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: <a href="#">проба кавыч"еч"ек</a>

Comment: И как проба?)

Comment: <a href=«#»>проба 'кавыч«еч»ек'</a>

Если это то, что ожидалось, то passed :-)

Comment: Ксли верно прочитать вопрос, то так нет упоминаний о валидности преобразования!

Comment: Это да :) Но что будет со строкой 'ля"ля"ля"ля' ?

Comment: холивар и извращения не практикую!

Comment: Почему извращения? В русском языке запросто может быть ситуация с непарными кавычками... Например, название учреждения "Институт "НИИСХ" или когда в конце предложения с прямой речью есть слово в косвенном значении... Меня это всегда вымораживало.